# forfiles has space in folder path

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, xcopy

I want to try the `bat` file to copy my log to other space.

My code:

```
REM get date
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a IN ("%date%") DO (SET _MyDate=%%d/%%b/%%c)
echo _MyDate: %_MyDate%    
set _path= "D:\Logs\AddressBook Service"
set _path2= "E:\Logs_test\AddressBook Service"
forfiles /p %_path% /d -%_day% /m *.log /c "cmd /c xcopy @path %_path2%"
```

My question is How to solve the forfiles @path has spaces in folder path?

Like this: `E:\Logs_test\AddressBook Service`

Comment: I try to used double quote, but won't work.

Comment: i find answer.
i add ^0x22e and every space add ^.

like this:
`forfiles /p %_path% /d -%_day% /m *.log /c "cmd /c xcopy @path ^0x22E:\Logs_test\AddressBook^ Service^0x22 /D /E /-Y"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "_day=2"                             only my guess
set "_path=D:\Logs\AddressBook Service"
set "_path2=E:\Logs_test\AddressBook Service"
forfiles /p "%_path%" /d -%_day% /m *.log /c "cmd /c echo xcopy @path \"%_path2%\\\" /D /E /-Y"
```

Above code snippet with proper [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) `"` double quotes (surprisingly escaped using a backslash `\"` instead of common caret) should result in something like

```
xcopy "D:\Logs\AddressBook Service\some name.log" "E:\Logs_test\AddressBook Service\" /D /E /-Y
```

Note that operational `xcopy` is merely displayed for debugging purposes. Remove `echo` keyword no sooner than debugged.
Adding a trailing backslash to `xcopy` target folder (`%_path2%\\`) seems to be facultative (optional) supplement.
Finally, note double quotes in `set "variablename=variable value"` syntax.

Comment: `\"` is the `forfiles`-specific escaping of `"`, so that the command after the `/C` switch receives `"` literally; you could also write `0x22`, which is the hex. code (ASCII) of `"`...